# AngularJS - connect ng-options to an object named in a property

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm working on a form generator implementation, and I want to have ng-options evaluate a property of the current 'field' and return the select 'options' as listed in something like $scope.options.

This means that I can setup the 'option' containing objects in my controller, and have the form elements use the correct object to populate the dropdown.

My form is built from a relational database, so hard coding the target object isn't going to help (although it does work, it's just not scalable)

I'm stuck figuring out how to get ng-options to evaluate an expression which makes the jump from variable to object name.

Maybe there's just a better way to do this altogether?

`<select id="{{field.Name}}" ng-model="field.Value"ng-options="option.ID as option.Value for option in [SOMETHING THAT EVALUATES TO AN OBJECT NAMED IN THE BINDING PROPERTY]" ng-required="field.Required"></select>`

I have a fiddle here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aS4Zj/1/)

Comment: You can use filter:field.Value to be able to filter based on one dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an object containing objects of your options

```
$scope.optiongroups = {group1: [...], group2: [...]}
```

and then

```
ng-options="value as option for option in optiongroups[dynamic var here]"
```

Comment: This answer has solved my problem very nicely.
I had to take out the Curly braces, and resolve some scoping issues, but it was the concept I needed. Thanks.